# Need help on java interfaces exercise

Tags: java, interface

I am still reading the Oracle docs for java. An exercise on interfaces really has me confused.
[CharSequenceDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/examples/CharSequenceDemo.java)

How does the length method implementation simply uses the method itself? And it doesn't seem to provide any statements to find the length of the string. Are those statements already written in the interface. But i thought only method signatures are written in the interface.

I'm new to java so simple answers would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a lot of great java tutorial in the internet. Try to start from familiarize with them

Comment: What do you mean by `If possible can you explain the class. `? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `CharSequenceDemo` is a Class not an Interface - so it can implement methods.

It implements the Interface `CharSequence`

There is a field `String s` stored within the `CharSequenceDemo`. The length method just calls the length() method of that string and returns the result.

I'm not going to run through the full class, try to work out what you can and come back with more specific questions :)

Next time it would be worth posting a link to the tutorial not just the source code.

Strings are fully fledged Java classes. (Generally the convention is that anything starting with a capital letter like String is a full class, anything else is primitives or variable names. For example int is a primitive, Integer is a fully fledged class.)

```
int i;
i.toString(); // Error, i is not an object

Integer i;
i.toString(); // Fine, i is an object
```

The String javadoc is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: So basically you are saying, string variables have length methods for them by default.(Sorry it was stupid of me to ask you to explain the class)

Comment: Yes, I'll edit with more info.

Answer (score 0):

The length method is calling `s.length()` which is the length method of the member variable string `s`